# Is there any way to automatically add many properties on VS2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

Don't judge me, but I have an object with over 100 properties, most of them string.
Is there anyway to automatically add them to the code, without extensive typing?
I have them all in a text file with correct casing. I looked for plug ins, but couldn't find any (maybe using wrong keywords?)

Comment: json deserializer ?

Comment: You mean add them as code? Not fill with data? - In the former case: Copy and Paste, then do minor corrections to match syntax.

Comment: If you know regular expressions. Copy into a text editor that can handle regular expressions. Modify your lines into properties and you are done.

Comment: @Fildor, I have a CSV file with 130 columns... I am importing a 130 column CSV file and I have to create constants for the columns, or properties for my model, and somehow to use the column names.
How would you suggest doing this more elegant?

Comment: @wizard I don't. Sometimes, we have to do things, we know we shouldn't. Like in this case, I guess it is one of those cases, where you bite your cheek and do it anyways although it makes you feel miserable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your file looks like:

```
Property
SomeOtherProperty
Test
```

The easiest way would be to use a **CSV -> C# Model generator**

### Steps

Change it to be comma separated, you can do this with C#:

```cs
var path = @"C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt";

var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");

File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Open the file and copy its contents to your clipboard.

Now open the [C# Class from CSV](https://toolslick.com/generation/code/class-from-csv) tool.

Paste the contents and voila you have a C# model!

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ can do it quite easily.

- Open your text file with notepad++ and press Ctrl+H
- Fill in the fields like below:

  - search for `(.*)`
  - replace with `public string \1 {get;set;}`
  - tick "regular expression"
  - press "Replace all"

[image: before replace]

And voilà:

[image: after replace]

---

Note that this should work with any editor that handle regex (as stated by @Klamsi in the comments section)